# Setting Script Tag's Attribute Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

Is it possible to set the value of `data-id` from the textbox with the id of `txtPublicProfileId`?

.aspx:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPublicProfileId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-format="inline" data-id=""></script>
```

Button-click event will assign the value of the textbox to `data-id` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the markup add a literal control where you want the script:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPublicProfileId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <asp:Literal ID="ltlMyScript" runat="server" Text='<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-format="inline" data-id="" ></script>' ></asp:Literal>
```

And in code add the script with the id to the literal:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ltlMyScript.Text = "<script type=\"IN/MemberProfile\" data-format=\"inline\" data-id=\"" + txtPublicProfileId.Text + "\"></script>";
}
```

And here's how it is rendered with the id:

[image]

Comment: data-id belongs to <script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-format="inline" data-id=""></script>. Nothing to do with the TextBox

Comment: Lovely. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

What id do you need? ClientID? Server ID?

```
txtPublicProfileId.Attributes.Add("data-id", txtPublicProfileId.ClientId)
```